# fast way to group points

Tags: python, numpy, math

I'm trying to group points together under certain conditions but I'm not sure I do it right.

Here is a sketch to make you understand what I mean

[image]

I'm trying to make the first 3 points and the 3 last points together in a general way (in this example it's group of 3 but it can be 4 or 2 for example).

To do this, I create a numpy histogram with max y value and min y values as bins with a 10% step and I extract the values where I have a detection. Then I'm averaging the points to have only one point for each group (including both centered circles here which are alone but importants).

But I think the code is really really heave for the purpose and take a bunch of time (1ms in my case). If I increase the number of circle it gonna be really hard to have something fast.

Do you have any solution or imporvement?

Here is my code:

```py
import numpy as np
import time

# circle points
cercle = [[103, 67],[100, 94], [101, 5], [97, 42], [105, 101], [102, -3], [98, 96], [107, 2]]

# timer's on
timer_init = time.time()

# sorting circle by their value in y
circles_sorted = sorted(cercle,key=lambda l:l[1], reverse=False)

# compute the max y, min y values and the step to have a 10% cutting
min_bin = int(np.array(circles_sorted).min(axis=0)[1])
max_bin = int(np.array(circles_sorted).max(axis=0)[1])
ten_percent = int((max_bin - min_bin) / 10)

# create a numpy histogram with circles_sorted and previous computed values as bins
value, bins = np.histogram(circles_sorted, bins = np.arange(min_bin, max_bin + ten_percent, ten_percent).tolist())

# finding where values are bigger than 0 (it means that there are some points here)
index_to_group = np.where(value>=1)

# cumulative sum for previous value of the histogram (usefull to select circles)
value_cumsum = np.cumsum(value)
for index in index_to_group[0]:
    # I need to take into account this 0 to avoid bugs
    if index == 0:
        coord_circles = circles_sorted[0:value_cumsum[index]]
        print(np.mean(coord_circles, axis = 0))
    else:
        # extract circles that has been counted in the same bin
        coord_circles = circles_sorted[value_cumsum[index-1]:value_cumsum[index]]
        # mean of its
        print(np.mean(coord_circles, axis = 0))

# display time it took
print('done in %.6f s'%(time.time()-timer_init))
```

EDIT : I'd like to have something fast. As mentionned by TYZ, sklearn.cluster.Kmeans could be really easier to read. The problem is, it takes 11ms on my CPU using this code:

```py
def get_circle_sklearn(cercle):
    min_bin = int(np.array(cercle).min(axis=0)[1])
    max_bin = int(np.array(cercle).max(axis=0)[1])
    ten_percent = int((max_bin - min_bin) / 10)
    value, bins = np.histogram(cercle, bins = np.arange(min_bin, max_bin, ten_percent).tolist())
    clusters = len(np.where(value>=1)[0])
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=clusters).fit(cercle)
    print(kmeans.cluster_centers_)

cercle = np.array([[103, 67],[100, 94], [101, 5], [97, 42], [105, 101], [102, -3], [98, 96], [107, 2]])
timer_init = time.time()
get_circle_sklearn(cercle)
print('done in %.6f s'%(time.time()-timer_init))
```

Comment: This feels like to me that you want to apply k-means clustering.

Comment: exactly! Bu k-means clustering is really really too long in my case it takes (using sklearn) about 100 ms !

Comment: 100ms doesn't sound like a lot. Does your function has an even stricter time limit? Considering you need to calculate the distance between the points for all points, k-means sounds like the exact out-of-box solution for your situation.

Comment: Yes, I tried sklearn Kmeans first with a large group of point (not as mentionned in this example) and it took way more time. I tried with the (small) group of point and sklearn Kmeans give me 11ms which is 10 times longer than the current method (which is numba compatible...)